# proof of convergence of EM algorithm with continuous hidden variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, references

I want to find the proof of convergence for EM algorithm in a case when hidden variables are continuous.
Do you know the proof of have a reference?
Thank you!

Comment: This is [cross posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492226/convergence-of-em-algorithm-with-continuous-hidden-variables) on math.stackexchange.com.